# Can I take one product payment at a time when I have two subscription products in the woo-commerce cart?

Tags: woocommerce, subscriptions, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am working on E-commerce site and I have an issue, is it possible that I have a two subscription product in the woo-commerce cart when I go on the checkout page it's take one product payment and apply subscription for only one product?

Comment: what is the issue? whether it takes one product in checkout or you need only one product in checkout?

Comment: I need two subscription product in the cart but when I go on the checkout page I need a payment of one product at a time and apply subscription for only one product.